# Returning an array of string words with more than 5 letters

Tags: java

Here is the problem specification:

**Write a static  method , getBigWords, that gets a single String  parameter  and returns an array  whose elements  are the words in the parameter  that contain more than 5 letters. (A word is defined as a contiguous sequence of letters.) 
EXAMPLE: So, if the String  argument  passed to the method  was "There are 87,000,000 people in Canada", getBigWords would return an array  of two elements , "people" and "Canada". 
ANOTHER EXAMPLE: If the String  argument  passed to the method  was "Send the request to support@turingscraft.com", getBigWords would return an array  of three elements , "request", "support" and "turingscraft".**

My approach was to declare a variable length array, and also split the string sequence into tokens pieces. Then I passed the tokens pieces into a method. Essentially, I wanted to check that each token element in the array with more than 5 elements has a contiguous sequence of letters. If not, break out of the loop and move to the next token. If so, add each letter in the token to a new array of String builders. Then, when all the loop iterations are done, I return the String builder array as a string array. I then assign the return value to the variable length array.

I am trying to figure out how to declare an array String builder. The array must be of variable length, to allow me to append letters to each element.

Here is my code.

```
public static String getBigWords(String string){
String[] tokens = string.split(" ");
java.util.ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

array = isNoDigit(tokens);

    public static String isNodigit(String[] param);
    StringBuilder[] builder = new StringBuilder[param.length];

    for (int i = 0; param.length(); i++){
        if (param[i].length() > 5){
            for (int j = 0; j < param[i].length(); j++)
                if ((Character.isLetter(param[i].charAt(j))){
                    builder.append(param[i].charAt(j));
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return builder.toString         
}
return array.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Updated code:

```
public static String[] getBigWords(String sequence) {
sequence = sequence.replace("@", " ");
sequence = sequence.replace(".", " ");
sequence = sequence.replaceAll("\\d+.", "");

java.util.ArrayList<String> array = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();

String[] tokens = sequence.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length(); i++) {
    if (tokens[i].length() > 5) {
        array.add(tokens[i]);
    }
}
return array.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I see a lot of words with nary a question mark...

Comment: The question seems to be _implicit_: _My code doesn't even compile, could you give me one?_

Comment: @user2491965: "(.*[a-zA-Z].*){5,}"

Comment: @user3580294 shouldn't it just be `"([a-zA-Z]{5,})"`? Seems like the .* would be greedy and if it is in the () then it would save it in the group.

Comment: @JeffWard I don't know, from how I'm reading the poster's specification it doesn't seem that the letters have to be consecutive. Could be that that was just left out, or I'm misreading it...

Comment: Also, I made a mistake... Should be `{6, 0}`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want. Obviously you'll need to take the code and implement it how you need to. This gives you the gist of how to use Regular Expressions to achieve your end goal in a much easier way. This finds any word greater than 5 letters (only letters a-z, upper or lower case) and adds them to an ArrayList object.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "There are 87,000,000 people in Canada";
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]{6,})").matcher(s);

        while (m.find())
        {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to learn more about regex, I recommend this tutorial: [**regexone**](http://regexone.com)

Answer (score 0):

Please note: This code is for demo only. I have not performed any error checking etc. You need to add that as fit for your application.
You can try something like this.

```
public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "There are 87,000,000 people in Canada";
        String str2 = "Send the request to support@turingscraft.com";

        String[] bigWordsArray = getBigWords(str1);

        System.out.println("Printing results from first String");
        for (String string : bigWordsArray) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
        bigWordsArray = getBigWords(str2);

        System.out.println("Printing results from second String");
        for (String string : bigWordsArray) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }

    public static String[] getBigWords(String testString) {
        testString = testString.replace('@', ' ');
        testString = testString.replace('.', ' ');
        testString = testString.replaceAll("\\d+.", "");

        String[] tokens = testString.split(" ");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String string : tokens) {
            if (string.length() > 5) {
                sb.append(string).append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().split(" ");
    }
}
```

**This compiles and works see the output below.**
[image]

Comment: I think the solution works but the program will not allow me to use List.

Comment: You can convert it to use array.

Comment: It won't allow me to use List or ArrayList for the variable length array. And I can't use the for each loop, so I am using the for loop instead.

Comment: Try now no arryalist. Only arrays. Same output though. If it works please mark it as answer :)